# How Do I Use collection_select Command for Multiple Values to Update A Second Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am developing a Media Library (model MediaLibrary) where I want to be able to assign multiple topics to each item.

I have created a model MediaTopic that will contain the id of the media library item and the topic id from the Topic model.

The MediaLibrary model has_many :media_topics.  The MediaTopic model belongs_to :media_library.

Here is my collection_select statement.

```
<%= f.label :topic, "Main Topic" %><%= collection_select(:media_library, :topic_id, Topic.order('name'), :id, :name, {prompt: true}, {multiple: true}) %>
```

I currently have :topic_id in the MediaLibrary model.  I got an obvious error where it is trying to write an array of ids into a single integer value.  I want to keep the current command without the **multiple: true** parameter and add a new command changing :topic_id to something that can hold more than one value then create the MediaTopic rows.  When I change :topic_id in the collection_select statement above I get an undefined method error.  My goal is to get the new logic working before I drop the column.

How do I capture the array that the above collection_select statement is creating?  Once I figure that out I can loop through the array and build my MediaTopic rows.  I thought about maybe using fields_for. However after seeing that I already have an array that the collection_select is creating I would like to just access the array and loop through it.

I have seen several solutions for more difficult situations on Stack Overflow.  I have tried piecing them together but to no avail.  I hope that since I know I am creating an array of IDs that somehow I can assign them to something in the collection_select statement.

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm obviously missing something that I will probably scream DUH if someone gives me the answer. I'm just not seeing it at the moment.

**UPDATE 2/18/2013 7:10 am**

Here is the code that I ended up using in my view:

```
<%= fields_for :media_topics do |media_topic| %>
  <%= media_topic.label :topic, "Topics" %><%= media_topic.collection_select(:topic_id, Topic.order('name'), :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true}) %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the code that I ended up using in my controller (create):

```
@media_library = MediaLibrary.new(params[:media_library])
@media_topics = params[:media_topics]
if @media_library.save
  if @media_topics
    @topic_ids = @media_topics["topic_id"]
    @topic_ids.each do |topic|
      if topic.blank?
      else
        @media_topic                  = MediaTopic.new
        @media_topic.media_library_id = @media_library.id
        @media_topic.topic_id         = topic.to_i
        @media_topic.save
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the code that I ended up using in my controller (update):

```
@media_library = MediaLibrary.update_attributes(params[:media_library])
@media_topics = params[:media_topics]
if @media_library.save
  if @media_topics
    MediaTopic.where("media_library_id = ?", params[:id]).destroy_all
    @topic_ids = @media_topics["topic_id"]
    @topic_ids.each do |topic|
      if topic.blank?
      else
        @media_topic                  = MediaTopic.new
        @media_topic.media_library_id = @media_library.id
        @media_topic.topic_id         = topic.to_i
        @media_topic.save
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In my loops I checked for the array item for blank because the 1st entry of the array was blank.  I assume it has something to do with the prompt feature.  Anyway my code is working well.  I have duplicated it with another model and will probably do this for two more.  Next trick is to add this to my already complicated search engine logic.

Comment: This will create params like this: `params[:media_library][:topic_id]`. "How do I capture the array that the above collection_select statement is creating?" >> `topic_ids = params[:media_library][:topic_id]` (you should delete this entry of the params before updating/saving the object, if not it'll raise an error)

Comment: I ended up having to work on other logic.  I got back to this yesterday.  I took a variation of what you suggested after I removed the topic_id field from my Model.  I ended up using a fields_for statement because of problems with not finding my field.  It is working well.  I have posted my final code in the description.  Thanks for leading me in the right direction.

Comment: Added as an answer by [Jill](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2325483/jill): *What specifically did you have to do for your edit method in the controller in order to bring up the edit page to show the select with the fields selected in the drop down?*

Comment: Jill, I have not found that solution.  I currently list what was selected on top of the dropdown list on the edit method.  If a person wants to change the list they have to enter all options they want. The views I have written so far are views only accessed by admins.  However I need to find a solution to this for my next project where these functions will have more exposure than to admins.  Any input from anyone would be appreciated :)

Comment: Jill, I was able to finally get the selected records displayed.  I ended up making the nested attributes for :media_topics AND I added f. to my fields_for statement.  That shows the selected records in the drop down.  NOW I want to use the accepts_nested_attributes_for process for updating.  Unfortunately the way I have the collection_select written my update blows up because I have a blank entry in the array.  I am adding a question for that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since I originally wrote this question I have rewritten my application in Rails 4.  I was able to develop a solution to this using has_many through and replacing my fields_for statement with a straight collection_select statement.  I ended up answering my own question.  The answer on the link below details how I finally solved this issue.

[Rails 4 - Using collection_select to get an array of ids for an Intermediate Table with Nested Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908309/rails-4-using-collection-select-to-get-an-array-of-ids-for-an-intermediate-tab)